# RedirectToAction with parameters in Route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have some problem with redirecting to some action basicly if I have no paramers on route or parameter which calls Id it works fine, yet when i add some different parameters to route RedirectToAction does not work, it throws an error: No route in the route table matches the supplied values.

```
[Route("First")]
public ActionResult First()
{
    //THIS DOESN'T WORK
    //return RedirectToAction("Second", new { area = "plans"});

    //THIS WORKS
    return RedirectToAction("Third", new { id = "12" });
}

[Route("Second/{area}")]
public ActionResult Second(string area)
{
    return new ContentResult() { Content = "Second : " + area};
}


[Route("Third/{id}")]
public ActionResult Third(string id)
{
    return new ContentResult() { Content = "Third " + id };
}
```

So when i enter /First it redirect correctly to Third but to Second it throw error.

I don't have anything extra in RouteConfig just:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably, you are conflicting the `area` parameter with `area` route parameters. [Areas is a resource from Asp.Net MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/714356/Areas-in-ASP-NET-MVC) with the following definition:

> Areas are logical grouping of Controller, Models and Views and other
>   related folders for a module in MVC applications. By convention, a top
>   Areas folder can contain multiple areas. Using areas, we can write
>   more maintainable code for an application cleanly separated according
>   to the modules.

You could try to rename this parameter and use it, for sample, try to rename the `area` to `areaName`:

```
[Route("First")]
public ActionResult First()
{
    return RedirectToAction("Second", new { areaName= "plans"});
}

[Route("Second/{areaName}")]
public ActionResult Second(string areaName)
{
    return new ContentResult() { Content = "Second : " + areaName};
}
```

Comment: You are right! It works which areaName, but is there a way to send area as argument ? Let's say that we have Route("{area}/Second") and how to redirect to different area?

Comment: Agreed. `{area}` is used by ASP.NET MVC when routing any Areas in the site. So would be advisable to rename that parameter something else to avoid confusion.